# Use of two external power sources for a power cell - charger

Tags: power, inductive

I have a [SparkFun Power Cell - LiPo Charger/Booster](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11231) and want to use the external 5V charge capability. Now my question:

Can I directly hook up a DC jack (for a 5V power supply) **and** an [inductive charging circuit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1407) to the external charge pins of the Sparkfun Power Cell LiPo Charger Module or should I use a slide switch so that **either** the power supply via the dc jack **or** the inductive charging module can power the Sparkfun Power Cell LiPo Charger? I prefer the first option, but I have concerns that the inductive charging module is damaged when for example the power supply is hooked up...

Have anybody experience with an similar setup?
 
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A switch would be the best way of preventing damage, but you could also use diodes to prevent power flowing back to the PSU or Inductive circuit.

I tried something similar once using transistors to prevent both circuits operating at the same time, but never managed to get it to work.  You could practice any solutions on a breadboard with some LEDs.